# Closed Question Help

Tags: support

[Link to closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247349/iphone-ipad-scaling-to-different-screen-size)

It was a simple question of if the tImage would scale properly from iPhone to iPad.

I posted a comment that I found the solution.

I wanted to post a photo to show how it worked for others to learn from.

Please tell me how a simple question of scaling was closed as not a real question.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a *give me the code* question which aren't welcome on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

As @juergen said in his comment, it was a poorly phrased question that could be (probably was) interpreted as a "*gimme teh codez*" or "*show me what to do*".

I don't think it was intended that way, so I've edited the question to change the phrasing and make it a little more obvious what is being asked, and I've cast a vote to reopen. If others also vote to reopen (i.e. if the community agrees) then things will be taken care of automatically (although the question will still retain its down votes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As Delphi XE4 Firemonkey Mobil app development is NEW i am sure there are others that want to know how to SCALE Up there controls on there forms to match both iPhone and iPad.